# ember - hide created.uncommitted records

Tags: ember.js

I need a little help about ember-data record creation.

My app is a basic one, with books and reviews, based on Code School Tutorial

The app is using the RESTadapter

There is a form on the book page to write and send a review

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-09">
    <h4>Reviews</h4>
    {{#each review in reviews}}
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p>{{review.text}}</p>
        <p class="text-info">{{review.reviewedDate}}</p>
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <p class="text-muted">No Reviews Yet. Be the first to write one!</p>
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h4>Review</h4>
    {{textarea valueBinding='review.text'}}
    <br>
    <button {{action 'createReview'}} class='btn-primary'>Review</button>
    {{#if review.text}}
    <br><h4>Preview</h4>
    <p class="text-muted">{{review.text}}</p>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

My Controller

```
App.BookController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    logoAvailable: 'images/instock.jpg',
    logoUnavailable: 'images/unavailable.jpg',
    logoAvailability: function () {
        if (this.get('isAvailable'))
            return this.logoAvailable;
        else
            return this.logoUnavailable;
    }.property('isAvailable'),
    review: function () {
        return this.store.createRecord('review', {
            book: this.get('model')
        });
    }.property('model'),
    actions: {
        createReview: function () {
            var controller = this;
            this.get('review').save().then(function (review) {
                controller.set('text', '');
                controller.get('model.reviews').addObject(review);
            }, function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                controller.set('text', '');
                review.unloadRecord();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My Models:

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isbn: DS.attr('string'),
    summary: DS.attr('string'),
    isAvailable: DS.attr('boolean'),
    featured: DS.attr('boolean'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('author', {async: true}),
    reviews: DS.hasMany('review', {async: true}),

    // computed properties
    image: function () {
        return 'images/books/' + this.get('id') + '.jpg';
    }.property('id'),
    isNotAvailable: function () {
        return !this.get('isAvailable');
    }.property('isAvailable')
});

App.Review = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    reviewedAt: DS.attr('date'),
    book: DS.belongsTo('book'),

    //Computed Properties
    reviewedDate: function () {
        return moment(this.get('reviewedAt')).format('LLL');
    }.property('reviewedAt')
});
```

The controller creates a new "review" object for each opened book, and will eventualy save it when the button is pressed.

This is working, but

My uncommited record is shown in the Book reviews list, even before submiting it, (as if it was a live preview), and before the call of `controller.get('model.reviews').addObject(review);`

What's wrong with my code, and how can I only display commited records (sucessful save() call).

Comment: Is coming from the ``{{each}}`` helper? ember doc: Like everything in Handlebars, the {{#each}} helper is bindings-aware. If your application adds a new item to the array, or removes an item, the DOM will be updated without having to write any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the reviews by the `isNew` flag.

in your `BookController` you could do something like this:

```
committedReviews: function () {
    return this.get('model.reviews').filter(function(review) { 
            return !review.get('isNew'); 
        });
}.property('model.reviews')
```

Comment: Used the ``isNew`` flag instead of ``isDirty`` [ember api](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isNew)